# Multidimensional Charts.js (array of arrays)

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm new in this area. I need to create a multidmensional chart with Charts.js, assumed it is possible.
My goal is to make a chart of a site's visits per month, taking data from an SQL databaser through a PHP interface file.
I'm now able to make a standard bar char, based on 'visits per page' or 'visits per month). I may extend this to get a 3D chart ('visits per page' per month)?
In my idea I should have a series of bars 'visits per page', separated per month; each serie should have its own label taken from the 'month' array.

Right now, in the PHP I create a multidemensional array in the form:

```
$combo[] = [ $month , [$page , $visits] ];
```

This is 'JSONized' and sent to a JQuery function which, with a JSON.parse(response) returns an array called 'downloaded' with contents:

```
[  
['jan',[page1,100]],['jan',[page2,150]],['jan',[page3,50]],['feb',[pag1,80]],['feb',[page2,120]],....   
]
```

After the JSON.parse it becomes:

```
'jan',page1,100,'jan',page2,150,'jan',page3,50,'feb',pag1,80,'feb',page2,120....
```

Assuminig this is correct, I do not now how to insert it into the chart structure, which is:

```
    var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ????
    ,       
    datasets: [ 
        {
        label: 'Visits per month',
        data: ????
        }
      ]

    },
});`
```

Hope this is almost a little clear.